# Filter a Component from a textbox VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs3

Can we show and hide a component based on textbox value? I saw v-if can do conditional rendering, but when textbox is null, nothing appear. And when i any character, both appear

What i want is just filter specific components

```html
<template>
<input type="text" v-model="search">
<ul>
  <li><ComponentA v-if="search.includes('ComponentA') || search.length == 0" /></li>
  <li><ComponentB v-if="search.includes('ComponentB') || search.length == 0" /></li>
</ul>
</template>
<script setup>
  import ComponentA from '../components/ComponentA.vue'
  import ComponentB from '../components/ComponentB.vue'
  import {ref} from 'vue'
  
  let search = ref('')
</script>
```

Comment: You haven't declared the variable `search`, so you're trying to access a non-existing variable :)

Comment: It should work. This error is not related to the conditional rendering.

Comment: i update the question